# Look up elements of a delimited string within an array - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have put together some sample data in a sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-UGs92D-7Ez_mW0zK12lAV5J2A50ch3hwCBarqpDxzs/).

Essentially I have a column with names separated by a pipe (col B in example). I have a separate table (col F:G) that maps each name to a role type. I want to add a column that looks up each individual person in the pipe delimited string and returns a similarly structured string containing their job roles.

I can do this on a row by row basis (see col C), but this is a table that will grow (and is sourced from elsewhere) so ideally I'd like to use an array formula that will work for every row. However, because of the SPLIT() in there I can't get this to work.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(B2:B, "|"), {F:F, G:G&"|"}, 2, 0))),,9^9))), 
 "\|$", ), "\| ", "|"))
```

[image]